# Can we merge these tags relating to careers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Do these tags mean essentially the same thing?

- [employment](/questions/tagged/employment)
- <del>[jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs)</del> - used for job scheduling; should not be merged
- [job-hunting](/questions/tagged/job-hunting)
- [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development)
- (possibly others)

If so, can we pick one and merge the rest into it?

Comment: [jobs] is used for job scheduling, might not be a good idea to massively retag it to an "employment" synonym.

Comment: @Mat: It seemed highly correlated with the tags listed above, but I see what you're saying. Looks like that tag could use a wiki and a lot of cleanup, but no merge.

Comment: As far as I remember, questions about careers/jobs are Off-Topic on SO.

Comment: @Bobby: I agree... related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51340/can-we-get-an-official-statement-regarding-career-advice-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92112/is-the-career-development-tag-a-honeypot Doesn't mean we shouldn't keep the tags tidy though-- there are still hundreds of these questions.

Comment: Also related to whether these tags are OT: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98683/whats-the-rule-about-where-to-post-programming-career-questions