# 99 bottles of beer vs 3 undelete votes

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, thresholds, vote-to-undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many votes are needed to undelete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51272/how-many-votes-are-needed-to-undelete)

Whenever I've checked undelete votes required, it always appears to be three.  To check, [find](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) any deleted question with undelete votes, read the tooltip for the number next to the undelete button.  Are undelete votes not scaled similarly to delete votes?

→ *[What disorders and diseases commonly afflict programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304287/what-are-the-common-disorders-diseases-the-programmers-suffer-from/)*
This currently has a score (sum of question and answers, including negative answers) of +181.  At 20:1 that's 9 extra votes, plus the original 3 means 12 to delete.  Yet just 3 undelete votes are required to reverse that decision.

**Should the number of undelete votes necessary be somewhere between the number of delete votes, to half that?**

For example, should 6 votes be required for that question? or 9? or the same count of 12?  Less undelete votes than delete votes makes sense, in a way.

That question is perhaps a poor example.  It was actually deleted at 11 votes, but the last was a moderator.  It also had 9 months to accumulate votes and is in that class of programmer-but-not-programming questions that attracts so much attention on SO.  OTGH, that it did attract so much attention and still was closed, stayed closed for a long time as off-topic, and yet was finally deleted, may make it a great example.

Comment: I beat ya to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51272/if-more-votes-are-needed-to-delete-a-popular-question-how-many-are-needed-to-the

Answer (score 3):

Very good point - we'll be scaling the number of votes required to undelete a question, as well.

The number of undelete votes required will currently scale at a **30:1 score to extra vote ratio**.  For example, a deleted question with a combined score + answers' score of 90 will require:

> 3 base votes
>   + 3 scaled votes (90 score/30 ratio)
>   = 6 undelete votes to undelete the question.

Comment: Please don't do that, while I don't want the question @The mentions to be resurrected, there are others that got hastily deleted before the vote scale change, that will now be hard to bring back to life.

Comment: @Lance: Flagging for moderator attention in that case, which should increasingly diminish, seems appropriate.

Comment: **This answer is out of date**; more recent answer is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/.